# Set row where datetime is between

Tags: mysql, datetime

I got an field named `last` in MySQL, it has an attribute: `datetime` so the `last` is displaying like this: `2012-01-27 20:21:35`, now I need to update rows with `datetime` bigger than `2012-01-20 20:00:00` so the query should look similar to:

```
UPDATE `player`
SET `hh` = `hh` + 1000
WHERE `last` > '2012-01-20 20:00:00'
```

Ofc. the above example won't work, but its just a sketch on how it should look like & what I want to reach.

How it can be done in MySQL query? Or maybe I'll have to use other language for this task?

Comment: Do you have a column called `hh`, or are you trying to update the Hour part of column `last`?

Comment: I got a column caled `hh` , and I want to increase it with 1000 for the every `player` row, where `last` field is bigger than 2012-01-20 20:00:00

Comment: @Cyclone: Can you add the table's definition (Create statement)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `unix_timestamp`

```
UPDATE `player`
SET `hh` = `hh` + 1000
WHERE unix_timestamp(`last`) > unix_timestamp('2012-01-20 20:00:00')
```

Comment: Lets delete this my answer, because Teez is the one who gave the real answer.